GSAP animations not showing when website is getting reloaded
I am trying to make a loading animation using GSAP in NextJS. I have created an artificial delay of 5s using setTimeout and wrote a loading animation file:
"use client";
 
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import gsap from "gsap";
import { useGSAP } from "@gsap/react";
 
gsap.registerPlugin(useGSAP);
 
export default function Loading() {
  const textRef = useRef(null);
 
  useGSAP(() => {
    gsap.from(textRef.current, {
      y: 400,
    });
  });
 
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen">
      <h1 ref={textRef} className="text-2xl">
        Loading...
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

but still, there is no effect on the word "Loading...". I have also installed all the required packages -> gsap and @gsap/react.
Can anyone help me out?

I think your issue is with useGSAP. Try to use the useEffect hook to trigger GSAP animations.


"use client";

import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import gsap from "gsap";

export default function Loading() {
  const textRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.from(textRef.current, {
      y: 400,
      duration: 1,
      ease: "power3.out",
    });
  }, []);
  
  ...



